# What is CURVE I : cannot open client INITIATE vouch?

Tags: volttron

I have a problem about forward historian.

I install volttron_central on PC called A, and then instlal volttron_sub on Raspberry pi.

I entered the command 'vctl auth keypair' on volttron_central,  and then I got the serverkey and secretkey.

and I install forward historian on volttron-sub, and running volttron-sub & volttron-central.

but I saw that 'CURVE I : cannot open client INITIATE vouch' on VOLTTRON_Central terminal.

I want to install forward historian on volttron-sub and send device(Philips-Hue) information to volttron-central machine.

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534520/how-can-i-debug-a-connection-issue-within-volttron is a reference worth looking at for context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure...

1. Login to PC called A.  From a volttron enabled console `volttron-ctl auth serverkey`.  This will give you the serverkey that you will use in any remote connection to PC called A.
2. Login to volttron_sub and get the publickey from the forwarder and voltron central platform agents by running `vctl auth publickey`
   `
3. (Back on PC called A) add the credentials from the forwarder and volttron central platform using `vctl auth add --credential <publickey>` for each agent.

NOTE: These instructions are assuming you are using releases 5.0 rc branch.